# installed heroku PGbouncer buildpack for my rails application. Console no longer has access to models or active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activerecord, buildpack

I Installed PGbouncer to help with transaction pooling, and so far it seems to be helping. However, when I do `heroku run console` my connection does not have access to ActiveRecord or any models.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord
    from (irb):8
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/countries-2.1.2/bin/console:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/bin/console:17:in `load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/bin/console:17:in `<main>'

irb(main):011:0> User
NameError: uninitialized constant User
    from (irb):11
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/countries-2.1.2/bin/console:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/bin/console:17:in `load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/bin/console:17:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by instead using

```
heroku run rails console
```

Had always used `heroku run console` up to this point. Could be useful information for people who have this problem in the future.